# how to backup centos7 that run several vm's with ovirt

Tags: centos, backup, virtual-machines, ovirt

I have a centos 7 machine. on this machine I've created several VM's using ovirt.
I want to create a backup that machine(all the vm's and the server itself).
I know there are many way to backup a server, but I'm not sure what is the best practice for such a backup?

Comment: How is your machine setup? Do you keep the VM files on a separate partition? If so, you can back them up separately from the host OS. That would be preferable, to separate host OS from the guest VMs.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking at cloning the disk , the best tool IMO would be dd. Just make sure you're booting from a live CD before running it since you shouldn't clone the disk while it's being used.

```
dd if=/dev/sdX of=/dev/sdY bs=32M
```

where if= is the disk that you'd like to clone and of= is the destination to which you'd like to save the backup to (could be a thumb drive,portable HDD etc)